# What would explain a file served via a CDN being 7/8th the expected size?

Tags: cdn, apk

I've got a Android .apk file that I want to distribute to a few 1000 devices but I don't want to put on the market, therefore I've decided to serve it via a CDN.

However the file I'm receiving via the CDN has been corrupted somehow.  It doesn't seem to have merely been truncated, at least the bytes that I've examined in a hex dump are all different.

For what it's worth I'm setting the mime type to be 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',  I think my problem might well be related to this.

It's suspicious to me that the file is close to 7/8th the original size - 1155060 vs 1321106 bytes.  This makes me wonder if the file is getting treated as 7 bit ascii somewhere along the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I've just realised that the file from the CDN is actually a gzipped version of the original.

I think I'm on the right track in thinking that the mime type is confusing the CDN & it's defaulting to gzipping the file.

I'm guessing the 7/8th file size difference is probably just a coincidence.

Edit:

Yes, this was it, a bodgy fix was to set the mime type to `application/zip`, which presumably doesn't confuse the CDN (I've got a custom updater so I can get around the fact that mime type is wrong).